# Cannot send Authorization Token in POST Ajax request - getting error - Request header field authToken is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, request-headers

I try to run this code an a web browser to access the taleo API.  I have already gotten the authToken by logging in.  I now need to use it to make subsequent calls.  However I get this error:   Request header field authToken is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.  Can someone tell me the best way to actually do this?

```
xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: logout,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false ,
        crossDomain : true,
        headers: {'authToken': Token }, 
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.status.success)
        }
      });
```

Comment: If you can log in successfully then there's a difference between that ajax call and this one.  What is different about them?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have cross domain issue.
see below question for better explanation:

[Cross domain AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234366/restful-webservice-how-to-set-headers-in-java-to-accept-xmlhttprequest-allowed)

Try this, you can set cross browser properties at client call also.

```
$.ajax({

        type:         "POST",
        url:          "test/test/test",
        dataType:     "text/xml",
        data:         "",
        processData:  false,       // default to true will parse data as an Array whereas we send XML
        contentType:  "text/xml",
        async:        false,
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS");
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
        },
```

Comment: Thank!  Is it even possible to do this without changing anything server side?

Comment: Thank!  I tried these and the error now give me: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.  How can one get around this issue?