# AngularJS $http get return null status 0

Tags: java, angularjs, arrays, json

I'm trying to create $http get request to fetch some json data generated by my web service, but it returns null error. However, the $http request works fine when I use this [sample url](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php) instead (it returns json string too)

This is my angular code :

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

  $http.get("http://localhost:8080/InventoryCtrl_Service/webresources/IVC_Service/GetUserList")
   .then(function(response) {
       console.log("success ");
   }, 
   function(response) {
       console.log("Error : " + response.data + " Status : " + response.status);
   }
});
```

This is my web service code :

```
@GET
@Path("/GetUserList")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response GetUserList() throws SQLException {

  net.sf.json.JSONObject json = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();       
  JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();    
  JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();  
  JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject();   
  JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();        

  obj1.put("Name", "Sara");
  obj2.put("Name","David");              
  arr.add(obj1);
  arr.add(obj2);

  outerObject.put("records", arr);

  return Response.status(200).entity(outerObject.toString()).build();
}
```

When I run the above code, it returns json string like this :

```
{"records":[{"Name":"Sara"},{"Name":"David"}]}
```

The console log returns this :

```
Error : null Status : 0
```

What is the meaning of the null error? Or is there anything wrong with how I return the json string?

Comment: Try `POSTMAN` to verify the response.

Comment: Do you have Spring on your backend?

Comment: @RohitJindal I used `POSTMAN`, and it returns `{"records": [{"Name": "Sara"},{"Name": "David"}]}`. The status shown is 200 OK.

Comment: Thats great. So, can you please change second function parameter from `response` to `error` and put this `"Error : " + error.data + " Status : " + error.status` inside console.log.

Comment: @RohitJindal tried it. the console log still shows the same error `Error : null Status : 0`

Comment: @TomePejoski nope i dont think so. but the web service i used is REST.

Comment: @justrandom i am not able to understand if you are able to get the data then why error function is executing.

Comment: @RJ do you think it might be caused by CORS not being enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to the response header, based on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234366/restful-webservice-how-to-set-headers-in-java-to-accept-xmlhttprequest-allowed). There's no problem with my angular code, it's just that I need to modify my web service code to enable the CORS. 
So I just modified the part where it returns data to become like this :

```
return Response.status(200).entity(outerObject.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`JSON_STRINGIFY`**, this will convert your incoming data into String format.

```
console.log(JSON_STRINGIFY(response.data));
```

TO verify what data your web service is returning, you can always check it by hitting your web service via [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests).

Comment: I tried this `console.log("Error : " + JSON.stringify(response.data));` and it still returns Error : null

Comment: First try hitting your url /web service via postman , its a chrome extension , if you are satisfied with the result it returns it means something is wrong with the angular code . Please verify it and let me know

Comment: try using 

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})

Comment: in your web service . This should resolve your concern

Comment: I used postman to call my web service url like you mentioned, and it returns this : `{"records": [{"Name": "Sara"},{"Name": "David"}]}`

Comment: try adding 
@GET @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_‌​XML})

Comment: I added it, @GET @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_‌​‌​XML}). Now the web service return 404 error. Seems like this one cant be used i guess?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131776/discussion-between-abhi-and-justrandom).