# Response is a 401 error when requesting local resource from http webpage

Tags: javascript

Chrome is throwing

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
>       http://127.0.0.1:8006/test 
>       No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is present on the requested 
>       resource. 
>       Origin 'http://xxx.yyy.com' is therefore not allowed access. 
>       The response had an HTTP status code 401.

I am opening a popup with HTTP and making a request to a local HTTP server created by Java.

It's working fine in all machines except in some different machine, the browser throws the above mentioned error.

As per my understanding, getting this error in `HTTP` to `HTTP` is a bit strange.

Comment: The problem isn’t the lack of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. That’s expected when the response is an error instead of a success message. The actual problem is that the response is a 401 instead of a 200 OK. And the fact that the response is a 401 has nothing at all to do with the CORS configuration in the server.

Answer (score 2):

It's not strange at all – `127.0.0.1:8006` and `xxx.yyy.com` are different origins, and the Java server is not sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that would tell the broswer it's okay.

More details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Basically, the Java server needs to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with either an allowed CORS origin or a wildcard (which would allow any origin):

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://xxx.yyy.com` (including the protocol, since http and https are different origins in the browser's eyes)

Comment: Allow Origin and Allow Headers both are already there. And if not, the same issue should occur on every machine. I tried requesting the same resource from Chrome Poster in the same machine and it's working.

Comment: What's the value in the allow-origin header? Can you please make a screenshot of the request details in devtools or that Poster extension?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add headers in server side where you are calling that URL for web service implementation. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236195/2802622) will help you to understand, how the headers are added in java.

**For e.g:**

`.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

If still you want to avoid the `cross origin` error. In this case, I suggest you to use this extension with chrome: **[Chrome extension for cors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)**.

This will help you to avoid cross origin error in browser only in your machine for the development purpose.

Comment: Allow Origin and Allow Headers both are already there. And if not, the same issue should occur on every machine. I tried requesting the same resource from Chrome Poster in the same machine and it's working.