# CORS while hosting angular7 app on tomcat production server

Tags: angular, tomcat, cors, angular6, angular7

I have production server say **ServerA** in which I have deployed my angular application. I am deployed it in **Tomcat** . Now I have another server which is serving backend calls say **ServerB** now when my angular application running on **ServerA** makes calls to **ServerB**. It is giving CORS issue.

Please note:- I am using https protocol

Any Idea how to make such calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServerB needs to set response headers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0):

Two options

1. Use a proxy kind of servlet in `Server A` and have a communication b/w `Server A` and `Server B`
   See : [Smiley's HTTP Proxy Servlet](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet#smileys-http-proxy-servlet)

or

2. Have a CORSFilter in `Server B` which accepts requests from `Server A` angular application
   See : [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234366/restful-webservice-how-to-set-headers-in-java-to-accept-xmlhttprequest-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to handle the origin. Here ServerB should accept request from ServerA and should sent header response as:-

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://ServerA.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: FooBar
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

I recommend to go this blog https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ for better understanding. This explains clearly on handling simple and not so simple requests.