# angular get method always going to error part

Tags: java, angular

I am writing a application in angular with java. Here I am writing a get method in angular, it is going to front end and the back end java service is returning a list of object. But the angular get method is directly going to error part.

**Java service:-**

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/getStatusMails")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getStatusMails() {
        List<Dto> status= sercice.getStatusMails(123);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(status, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**angular get method: -**

```
    this.httpClient.get<any>('http://IP:8090/getStatusMails').subscribe(
    data => this.elements = data,
    error => console.error('There was an error!', error))
```

I have tested with postman, it is getting the proper list of objects.

**My console error: -**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://IP:8090/getStatusMails' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET http://IP:8090/getStatusMails net::ERR_FAILED
core.js:6241 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://IP:8090/getStatusMails", ok: false, …}
```

If I write my code like below

```
const url = "http://IP:8090/getStatusMails"; // site that doesn’t send Access-Control-*
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(contents => console.log(contents))
    .catch(() => console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?"))
}
```

In my console I am getting the console like  `Can’t access http://IP:8090/getStatusMails response. Blocked by browser?` When I click on my url in the log, I am able to see the output in another window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about the HTTP code ?

Comment: @Random it is not showing any http code, it is just showing "Unknown Error"

Comment: message: "Http failure response for http://IP:8090/getStatusMails: 0 Unknown Error"

Comment: I mean, if you use Chrome, you can see the HTTP request in the "network" tab, and that will show you the HTTP code. Same in POSTMAN.

Comment: In postman it is 200 ok,

Comment: @Random I have updated my question with network error

Comment: Do you see any failed requests or any redirects before the failed one in your network console?

Comment: When you click on the request, you should see the detail

Comment: @Random I have updated the my question please find

Comment: @MikeOne I have updated my question with the console error

Comment: Your error is now clear: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://IP:8090/getStatusMails' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @Random I have updated my question, Please look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Http error code 0 is caused by [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing): your Angular application is hosted on a different host than your Java application and XHR requests are forbidden.

To solve this, you can either use a reverse proxy (recommended) or add Access Control http headers to your backend.

### Using a reverse proxy

#### During development

Create a `proxy.json` file in the same folder than your `package.json`:

```
{
    "/getStatusMails": {
        "target": "http://IP:8090",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And start your Angular dev server with `--proxy-config proxy.json` :

```sh
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.json
```

Now instead of sending a request to `http://IP:8090/getStatusMails`, you can simply request `/getStatusMails`.

If you have multiple services, you can define a common prefix for them (like `/api` or `/rest`):

- `/api/getStatusMails`
- `/api/getUsers`

(Although I would recommend following [REST naming conventions](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)).

And then configure the proxy using the prefix:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://IP:8090",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

In production, you either have to deploy everything on the same Java server or you have to configure a reverse proxy in your web server (Apache Httpd or Nginx).

#### Apache Httpd

You have to enable `mod_proxy` and then you can configure it with `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`:

```
ProxyPass         "/getStatusMails" "http://IP:8090/"
ProxyPassReverse  "/getStatusMails" "http://IP:8090/"
```

You can find more information on [Apache Http documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html).

#### Nginx

Using `proxy_path` property:

```
location /getStatusMails {
    proxy_pass http://IP:8090/;
}
```

You can find more information on [Nginx documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).

### Using Access Control http headers

In this configuration, user's web browser will send an OPTION request before sending the real XHR request.

Your Java application have to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`  headers to allow cross origin requests.

For example, during development you could send:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

To allow GET and POST requests from any URLs.

In production, you should never use `*` and always specify the real URL of your frontend.

Since you seems to be using Spring, you can simply annotate your method with `@CrossOrigin` to send these headers. You can find more information about this in  [Spring documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

Comment: Do I need to do this process for each and every get method? if so is there any alternate for this?

Comment: There is an other way, you can use a prefix like /api or /rest for your services and map the reverse proxy to the prefix

Answer (score 1):

This is a CORS error.

This occurs when your client is running on a different server than that of backend.

so why this doesn't occur in Postman?

- postman is for development purpose and doesn't have any built-in checks for the origin

why does this happen in the browser?

- browsers checks for origin to prevent CSRF attacks.

The solution to your problem is to add your client's URL in 'Allow-Acess-Control_origin' at your server-side.
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234366/restful-webservice-how-to-set-headers-in-java-to-accept-xmlhttprequest-allowed) on how to do that.

you can either set 'Allow-Acess-Control_origin'to * , (accept all connections)
or you can specify the client URL's

Answer (score 0):

Adding @CrossOrigin annotation to your controller in your Java service should fix your issue.

```
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping(value = "/getStatusMails")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getStatusMails() {
        List<Dto> status= sercice.getStatusMails(123);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(status, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to configure your Spring Boot application to include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response to the preflight OPTIONS request, as well as in the actual POST request. You can do this using Spring Security's CORS support or by adding a custom CORS filter.

So create your CORS registry class as below.

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebMvc

public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
    corsRegistry.addMapping("/getStatusMails") //modify the mapping  
                                                 //to your Request mapping
     .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
     .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
     .allowedHeaders("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization")
     .allowCredentials(true);
}
```

}