How to retrieve Angular application logged in user in Java API
I am trying to retrieve logged in user in my Java Application. I tried to call it from angular application authentication module but it did not worked well. So finally setup username and password in Insomnia as basic authentication and then called. Still at API side unable to retrieve user. I have tried various ways. But all are returning null. Not sure what is going wrong.
Secondly in response it is giving CORS issue. I implemented WebSecurityConfig for same but no luck.
API
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.security.Principal;


@CrossOrigin
@RestController()
public class AbcController {
    @GetMapping("/getUserName")
    public String getUserName(HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println(request);
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteUser());  //prints null
        System.out.println(request.getUserPrincipal()); //prints null

        //prints anonymousUser        
        System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()); 

        return request.getRemoteUser();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getUserNamePrincipal")
    //principal is null
    public String getUserNamePrincipal (Principal  principal ){  
        System.out.println("principal.getName() : "+principal.getName());

        return principal.getName();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getUserNameAuthentication")
    //authentication is null
    public String getUserNameAuthentication(Authentication   authentication){   
        System.out.println("authentication.getName() : "+authentication.getName());

        return authentication.getName();
    }


    @GetMapping("/getUserNameAuthenticationPrincipal")
    //userDetails is null
    public String getUserNameAuthenticationPrincipal(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails){  
        System.out.println("userDetails.getUsername() : "+userDetails.getUsername());

        return userDetails.getUsername();
    }
}

Config
package com.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
            @Override
            public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                return new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
            }
        });
    }
}

POM
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
        </dependency>


What HTTP status does Insomnia returns when performing the request ?

{
"timestamp": "2024-09-02T11:06:18.416+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "",
"path": "/getUserNameAuthenticationPrincipal"
}

This might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234366/restful-webservice-how-to-set-headers-in-java-to-accept-xmlhttprequest-allowed

By default Spring security wouldn't returns a 500 for a CORS issue or an unauthenticated request. I'm pretty sure you should have an exception thrown at some point, could you share it ?

Basically It is getting authentication as null. So when applied authentication.getName() it is thrwing null pointer exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.Controller.getUserNameAuthentication(Controller.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod..........

It looks like your endpoints are not protected by Spring Security.
If you apply the following configuration for your security context it should solve the issue:
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .cors().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().httpBasic();
}

Basically it tells Spring Security to allow CORS (for convenience of quickly testing with Angular), then that all requests should be authenticated, and finally to allow basic authentication (username + password).
You can then perform a request on one of your endpoint configuring your HTTP client to use basic auth then you should get your current user name in the response.
ex: curl -v -u user:07db6b99-a70f-4d26-9c35-64275be8fb5e --basic localhost:8080/getUserNameAuthenticationPrincipal
where 07db6b99-a70f-4d26-9c35-64275be8fb5e is the generated password by Spring Security at the begining of your logs:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2024-09-04 15:24:28.897  INFO 51553 --- [           main] com.example.demoso.DemoSoApplication     : Starting DemoSoApplication on APLAFAT351406.local with PID 51553 (/Users/gillesgardet/repositories/demo-so/target/classes started by gillesgardet in /Users/gillesgardet/repositories/demo-so)
2024-09-04 15:24:28.898  INFO 51553 --- [           main] com.example.demoso.DemoSoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2024-09-04 15:24:29.226  INFO 51553 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-09-04 15:24:29.228  INFO 51553 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-09-04 15:24:29.228  INFO 51553 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2024-09-04 15:24:29.248  INFO 51553 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-09-04 15:24:29.248  INFO 51553 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 335 ms
2024-09-04 15:24:29.293  INFO 51553 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 07db6b99-a70f-4d26-9c35-64275be8fb5e

I hope it helped.
BTW you should upgrade your spring-boot dependencies because 2.3 is deprecated since a long time.
edit: here I've disabled CORS for convenience, you should of course never do this and instead handle this appropriately on Angular to send back the token

Thank you for your help Gilles. But very little understood.  I am new to this whole. when I am trying now its giving me 401 unauthorized. Let me check on this.

No problem, Spring Security got a high learning curve at start. Let me know if I can help.
